# Symfony2 Relation between entities cross Bundles and multiple entity manager

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony 2.7. I followed documentation on Symfony2 about [How to Work with multiple Entity Managers and Connections](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html). I tried every solutions on this site but without success. I have always the same error :

> [Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]   The class
>   'Spot\OfferBundle\Entity\Offer' was not found in the chain configured
>   namespaces Dashboard\ProjectBundle\Entity

In my project, I have 2 bundles. Every bundle works with a different entity manager. Here my config file :

```
    # Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection:       default
    connections:
        default:
            driver:   %database2_driver%
            host:     %database2_host%
            port:     %database2_port%
            dbname:   %database2_name%
            user:     %database2_user%
            password: %database2_password%
            charset:  UTF8
        spot:
            driver:   %database3_driver%
            host:     %database3_host%
            port:     %database3_port%
            dbname:   %database3_name%
            user:     %database3_user%
            password: %database3_password%
            charset:  UTF8
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    default_entity_manager:   default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection:       default
            mappings:
                DashboardProjectBundle: ~
        spot:
            connection:       spot
            mappings:
                SpotOfferBundle: ~
```

I have two entities with relations across bundles
The first :

```
namespace Dashboard\ProjectBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Project
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="project")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Project
{
     /**
     * @var Spot\OfferBundle\Entity\Offer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Spot\OfferBundle\Entity\Offer", inversedBy="projects")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="offer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $offer;
```

And the second :

```
 namespace Spot\OfferBundle\Entity;
 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

 /**
  * Offer
  *
  * @ORM\Table(name="offer")
  * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Spot\OfferBundle\Entity\OfferRepository")
  */
 class Offer {
        /**
        *  
        * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Dashboard\ProjectBundle\Entity\Project", mappedBy="offer")
        */
        private $projects;
```

I try with use statement, I check AppKernel and Bundles are defined. I try with leading backslashes. But nothig works.

Comment: check [this](https://techpunch.co.uk/development/using-multiple-databases-with-symfony2-and-doctrine2) article

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Make sure that you have set this in the config file:

```
assetic:
    ...
    bundles:        [ DashboardProjectBundle, SportOfferBundle]
```

**UPDATE:**

Also, try to set orm config like this:

```
orm:
auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
default_entity_manager:   default
entity_managers:
    default:
        connection:       default
        mappings:
            DashboardProjectBundle: ~
            SpotOfferBundle: ~
    spot:
        connection:       spot
        mappings:
            SpotOfferBundle: ~
```

Comment: Do the assetic configuration have an impact on the Doctrine mappings?

Comment: I don't really know, but he can give it a try.